# Linq to Entites Count Where Clause Syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I have a Linq to Entites query that needs to run only when `ProgramId` equals the parameter passed in by the URL:

```
var PatientFollowUpResult = surveyResponseRepository.Query.Count(r => r.PatientFollowUp);
```

For example, how do I count all of `r.PatientFollowUp` for `r.ProgramId = 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you might have multiple hit based on the passed parameter and you are trying to get the total count for all these matches for a property on each?

In that case where and SelectMany would do the trick

```
var count = surveyResponseRepository.Query
                      .Where(r => r.ProgramId ==1)
                      .SelectMany(r=>r.PatientFollowUp).Count()
```